# Isaiah 46:10 and the implications of verse 11: Do any modern theologians dare pay attention to verse 11?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 46:10 is of course the famous passage which says `"Declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things that are not yet done, saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all my pleasure:"` which has been used to great affect by Calvinists as a bludgeon against any other theological framework.  But it is immediately followed by the always ignored verse (verse 11):

> Calling a ravenous bird from the east, the man that executeth my counsel from a far country: yea, I have spoken it, I will also bring it to pass; I have purposed it, I will also do it.

This gives it a rather specific context, limiting it to speaking of the fulfillment of the threats in Deuteronomy 28 and takes away its biased use as a magical proof-text for absolute determinism. (I.e. the "ravenous bird" is a foreign nation that will take Israel into captivity, per the warnings in Deut 28 of what will happen to the nation if it persists in disobedience.)

So my question is, are there any modern scholars/theologians/commentators who dare publicly take that position? Are there any citations anyone knows of in which anyway has the spine to take this more obviously contextual position?

(This is not a duplicate of [What is the meaning of, "I make known the end from the beginning" in Isaiah 46:10?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/what-is-the-meaning-of-i-make-known-the-end-from-the-beginning-in-isaiah-461) because I'm not simply asking for the meaning, but about the scholarly acceptance or not of the possible but rarely publicly used interpretation which actually bothers to take verse 11 into account.)

Comment: Please can you join the dots - how specifically are you suggesting verse 11 ought to be interpreted as fulfillment of Deuteronomy 28?

Comment: also I suspect this will be closed in its present form: "are there any modern scholars..." [doesn't lend itself](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/1043/43) to the format here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant rather than a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

### Probably Not, since v.11 is only a Specific Example of the Universal

Your questions are (as they stand at this writing):

> So my question is, are there any modern
>   scholars/theologians/commentators who dare publicly take that
>   position? Are there any citations anyone knows of in which anyway has
>   the spine to take this more obviously contextual position?

The position you are referring to is that which state in your question, namely that:

> This [v.11] gives it [v.10] a rather specific context, limiting it to speaking of
>   the fulfillment of the threats in Deuteronomy 28.

The problem is that it would be a logical fallacy to hold that position (hence why it is unlikely any do hold it—though a few might, illogically, which would probably not be a factor of how much "spine" they had). It is illogical because the *specific instance* of v.11 where God is stating something He is declaring He will do (whether aligned to Deut 28 or not) in no way limits the *universal statements* of v.9-10.

Rather, God is founding His ability to make the call in v.11 on His universal sovereignty declared in v.9-10 (a major factor that makes Him ***God***, such that there is "none like" Him, as v.9 states, is this freedom and ability at the universal scale).

So v.11 has no *limiting* force at all to v.9-10, but rather is a pictoral instance of the universal declared in the preceding verses.

To illustrate further, here is an outline of the essence of the position you seek to find if anyone holds:

```
God can do whatever He pleases and knows what will come (so v.9-10).
God has declared He will do this one thing (so v.11).
Therefore, God can and desires only do this one thing He declared He would do.
```

It is pretty clear that such logic does not hold. There is nothing limiting God's pleasure and ability by His doing the one thing He declares He will do. Rather, the argument is more of this form:

```
God can do whatever He pleases and knows what will come (so v.9-10).
God has declared He will do this one thing (so v.11).
Therefore, God is pleased and able to do this one thing He has declared, 
    and knows that it will come to be.
```

All that v.11 shows is that God will do what v.11 states, and that He is pleased and able to do so even while also knowing it shall be done (based on v.10). There is no limitation on the clear, universal language of v.10 just because an instance is noted in v.11.

**Thus, I would not expect anyone to hold the view you note.**

### No Grammatical Issues to Void the Logic

The logic flow noted above is not voided by the grammatical structure of the Hebrew. Verses 8-11 form a "section" of thought (indicated by the small *samek* [`ס`] placements in the Masoretic text; [see 3rd paragraph of section 2 here](http://www.bible-researcher.com/hebrewtext1.html#chap2sect2)). Such a section may be considered like a paragraph with respect to grouping of the subject matter.

Verses 10 and 11 are considered two sentences of this section, as the *[sof pasuq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation#Colon_and_sof_pasuq)* (`׃`) division indicates between the verses:

```
10      מַגִּ֤יד מֵֽרֵאשִׁית֙ אַחֲרִ֔ית וּמִקֶּ֖דֶם אֲשֶׁ֣ר לֹא־נַעֲשׂ֑וּ אֹמֵר֙ עֲצָתִ֣י תָק֔וּם וְכָל־חֶפְצִ֖י אֶעֱשֶֽׂה׃
        |
       here is the sof pasuq dividing the verses
11      קֹרֵ֤א מִמִּזְרָח֙ עַ֔יִט מֵאֶ֥רֶץ מֶרְחָ֖ק אִ֣ישׁ עֲצָ֯תִ֑ו אַף־דִּבַּ֙רְתִּי֙ אַף־אֲבִיאֶ֔נָּה יָצַ֖רְתִּי אַף־אֶעֱשֶֽׂנָּה׃
```

Each verse in the section is its own sentence, ending in a *sof pasuq*. The sentences build an argument flow through the section something like so:

```
(1) There is a call to remembrance (v.8)
(2) The remembrance was that the true God (speaking to them) is unique (v.9)
(3) Unique because only He is able to do whatever He pleases and know what will come about (v.10)
(4a) An example of the power in v.10 is His then present calling of a man
    from the east for judgment (v.11a)
(4b) Which He intends as a demonstration of His ability to bring about what He wills and 
    know that such will come to pass as v.10 stated (v.11b)
```

So there is no issue in the Hebrew text of following a "fallacy that each verse is its own sentence" that might disturb the logic flow of the argument. Each English verse was considered its own sentence in the Hebrew text in Isaiah 46:8-11, and in both, it is building a concise argument of how God is truly God, unique in His ability to do what He wills, and unique in His knowledge to know it will come to pass and be able to declare it before it ever happens, even when such involves the actions of other men (such as this man from the east).

### Not Necessarily Supporting "Absolute Determinism"

This part is getting slightly more theological, only because that is obviously the motive behind your question.

It seems the motive you see in seeking another reading is apparently because the non-limited reading is used "as a magical proof-text for absolute determinism." It may be so used (I will not argue the merits of that charge or not, simply because I see that it *could* be used that way, which is good enough), but that is not the only position one can take with God having a universal ability to do whatever He may be pleased to do. That is, if God is pleased to allow a creature of His to have some choice in matters, He is certainly able (by these verses) to do so, and God can still know and declare "the end from the beginning" with those choices to yet come.

Debating either for or against absolute determinism and God's foreknowledge and such is ***WAY*** out of scope for this site, and I will go no farther than what I have above.

### Conclusion

As far as hermeneutics goes, the natural reading of God's *universal* ability, pleasure, knowledge, and practice of fore-declaration of history stands without need of limitation, but more importantly, without warrant to logically limit the greater power by an illustration of a single instance of that power being expressed.

Comment: Its only a universal statement if you fall for the fallacy that each verse is its own sentence.  The Bible often has runon sentences that go on for 2 or 3 verses, and its obviously the case here.

Comment: The Bible does not have many [true runon sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence), but does have many [compound and/or complex sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_sentences#Compound_sentences). I've updated with a discussion of the sentence structure of the Hebrew in the passage.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on ScottS, v11 is simply an application v10.  Most of the major Calvinist preachers/teachers I am aware of do not shy away from v11 as much as they simply cut to the "heart" of it in v10.

The entire book of Isaiah shows God's undisputed sovereignty over Israel's fate.  Yes, v11 absolutely is a fulfillment of Deut 28's promises.  However, read Isa 10.  God sends Assyria to punish Israel -- and then turns around and judges Assyria for what they do.  Assyria is an "axe" in God's hand, yet he also judges them.  This is a demonstration of God's sovereignty.

With that in mind, it's difficult to make the case that 46:10 is limited only to what God is doing with Assyria.  Because that could not even be true (or effective) without the greater fact of God's absolute sovereignty being true.

Comment: The point is that God declared this end (a conditional end, for Deut 28 is a conditional prophecy/promise with two forks) from the beginning (of the nation, not creation). So no, verse 11 is not just an application of a verse on absolute determinism, but verse 10-11 together are its utter demolition.

Comment: I think you're missing the broader context of God's total sovereignty. It is a pretty common form for the OT to state (and show) God's "universal" declaration of the end from the beginning.  Look at the language: "from ancient times" (not just from a few hundred years ago).  It talks about God's purpose (which is not "conditional") twice.  Clearly, what is in mind is accomplishing God's purpose, and Israel's judgment is a component of that.

Comment: `"from ancient times" (not just from a few hundred years ago)` I frequently call the Reformation era "ancient times" and it was only 400 years ago, so no, I don't agree at all. Can you prove that ancient requires more than a few hundred years? Can you demonstrate an *absolute* definition with a set number of years? Of course not. Nor is it stated that the purpose is not conditional.

Comment: @david, that's simply not a reasonable approach, reading a modern, colloquial, even humorous use of "ancient" back into 3500 year old Hebrew. The reality is that the context of Isaiah and the demonstration of God's absolute (yes, absolute!) sovereignty dismantles the idea that the *only* thing in mind in 46:10 is temporal, conditional fulfillment of Deut 28.

Comment: So what you're saying is that when Proverbs 22:28 says "Remove not the ancient landmark, which thy fathers have set" it allows them to remove the landmarks that are 400 years old only, just not the ones that are 3500 yeas old?  Yea, your whole argument is discredited by that little oversight.

Comment: @david, I'm guessing you did a word search on "ancient" in an effort to find a place where "ancient" could refer to a relatively recent time period. I understand the gesture, but if you compare Isa 46:10 and Prov 22:28 in the Hebrew, the same words are not used. In other words, you are comparing apples and oranges, at least here, and Prov 22:28 is irrelevant to this topic.